# The action principle is the statement about minimizing something around trajectory

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I watched the special relativity lecture (4) for Prof. Susskind and about some last minutes of it, he said:

> "*The action principle is the statement about minimizing something around trajectory*".

I know the action totally but I don't quite understand this sentences as a general description.

Could anyone give me some clue?

Comment: Do you know the [principle of least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)?

Comment: Link to lecture?